# Voice activated and silence deactivated audio recording software

Tags: software-rec, audio, recording, voip

I plugged my PBX into the microphone hole in my PC's sound card, in order to record all activity on my PBX  in MP3 format.  I am using the software called "Recordpad", by NCH.  The problem is the software is only able to be sound activated, but it will continue recording when there is silence. Can anyone recommend a software that will stop recording when the phone conversation ends?